# UIViewController custom init method does not show

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have seen how to create your own custom init method I have one that looks like this

```
- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        currentArray = array;
        NSLog(@"%@", currentArray);
    }

    return self;
}
```

however when I try to call it i can never see **initWithArray** this is the way I call it.

```
if (![pictureViewController.view superview]) {
    pictureViewController= [[PictureViewController alloc] init];
    pictureViewController.stackRotationController = stackRotationController;
    [pictureViewController ini = pluginsMutableArray]; // cannot see initWithArray
    [pictureViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    pictureViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, ScreenHeight, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
    pictureViewController.prefToolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ScreenWidth, 45.0);
    [pictureViewController.view addSubview:pictureViewController.prefToolBar];
    [[UIToolbar appeara}nce] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:colorController.oRed/255.0 green:colorController.oGreen/255.0 blue:colorController.oBlue/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

Comment: You are not calling `initWithArray:` anywhere in that code. So what is supposed to call it?

Comment: Also that is not how to write an initializer for a UIViewController, if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: Even if were able to call it at this line `[pictureViewController ini = pluginsMutableArray];` it would be wrong, because you have already initiated it where you allocated it, but as @matt said you don't initialise `UIViewControllers` that way.  It is probably simpler to use a property for your array and set it after initialisation

Comment: hi @matt, can you give us a proper way to initialize an `UIViewController` ? I usually write my code like this. Does it has to have anything like `addChildViewController` ?

Comment: You have to take into account what is the designated initializer when you write your own initializer. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW58

Comment: yes sorry that was edited code when I was trying to call it... thanks matt looking now.. also I dont know how to write an initmethod which is why i am having trouble.

Comment: Did you declare `- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array` in your interface file?

Comment: no i havent... im not sure how to do it.. well I know how to create methods in the interface file... is that all I do?

Comment: okay that worked.. I didnt know I had to do that as I was using the initwithnib as an exmple which dose not have anything declared in the .h file...